# Concatenation encodes '<' of HTML tags to &lt;/

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

I'm creating articles viewer, and I'm pushing content out of object. In a loop, I do concatenation like this:

```
$content=$content.'<input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" name="articlecheck[]" value="'.$printarticles[$i]->article_id.'"/>
                               <div class="art_head">'.$printarticles[$i]->article_name.'< /div><!-- #art_head -->
                               <div class="art_body">'.$printarticles[$i]->article_code.$printarticles[$i]->article_name.$printarticles[$i]->short_desc.$printarticles[$i]->full_desc.'< /div><!-- #art_body -->';
```

For some, to me, strange reason, Instead of closing  after "art_head" and "art_body", I get it printed out on the screen, and if I take a look in the "code" it is encoded to "</div>".

Why ? What am I doing wrong, since I'm doing it all the time like this, and I never had this kind of problems.

Tnx

Comment: Take a look at [`htmlspecialchars`](http://de2.php.net/htmlspecialchars) and [`htmlentities`](http://de2.php.net/htmlentities), they're likely to get called somewhere in your framework and replace the characters.

Comment: Well, I'm using my own code, so I'm not using any "html's" mentioned. Problem appears in container that is swapped using ajax function:    $.post(url +  '&ajax=1', function(data) { $('#myPresentDiv').html(data);});return false; 

But I don't see how and if this might cause a problem ?
I'm pushing mentioned content into "#myPresentDiv" using ajax post